# Foster's Reactance Theorem - Reactance Increasing with Frequency?

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, reactance

I'm currently reading a text on analog filters (Zverev) that discusses Foster's Reactance Theorem in relation to passive circuits and I was thrown a little by the text that says: "*Physically, this signifies that the impedance or admittance of the reactive network always increases in value when the frequency is increasing*" (Pg 37 for those with the book).

Then the description of the theorem on wikipedia ([wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foster%27s_reactance_theorem)) has a similar line: "*It is easily seen that the reactances of inductors and capacitors individually increase with frequency and from that basis a proof for passive lossless networks generally can be constructed*".

I'm obviously missing something, but I always thought that the reactance of a 
capacitor *decreased* with *increasing* frequency.  What don't I understand?

Comment: Clearly that wiki page is wrong.

Comment: @Andyaka Foster's uses reactance in the sense of the imaginary part of the impedance, which has sign. A capacitor's reactance increases from large negative at low frequencies up closer and closer to zero as the frequency increases, even though the magnitude of that is decreasing. Interesting concept, I might try to wrap my head round that properly.

Comment: @Neil_UK I'm not sure what you are driving at.

Comment: @Andyaka The wiki page is not necessarily wrong. Increasing absolute is not inconsistent with decreasing magnitude.

Comment: Ah, quite possible but I thought the whole point was one of monotonicity and it needn't have said the confusing thing about a capacitor's reactance rising with frequency because monotonicity works just as well in either direction.

Comment: @Andyaka I suspect (haven't got my head round all the implications yet) that the rising is the important thing, there's a lot in Zverev that I don't understand. I d'on't think it's as trivial as noticing that reactance of single component changes monotonically, I think it generalises to passive networks, so I suspect it's going to go on to the derivation of getting the values out of the polynomial expansion. Now there's something I wish was more intuitive.

Comment: It depends how you choose to define reactance - with or without a \$\small j\$ in front of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foster's Theorem uses reactance in the strict mathematical sense of the imaginary part of the impedance. This is of course signed. By convention, a capacitor's reactance is negative. At low frequency, it's large negative. At higher frequencies, it increases towards zero. This is opposite to the *magnitude* of the reactance, which of course decreases with increasing frequency. Read the whole of that wikipedia article carefully. What's wrong with the wiki article is it says 'It is easily seen ...', it can be seen, but not easily.

[image]

Image from the wikipedia article

These both show reactance increasing (becoming more positive) with frequency.

Comment: I agree.  It's not easily seen!